# Native Resolution Displaying Incorectly on Primary monitor only when Second Monitor Is Active

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, resolution

I just purchased an AOC e2050Swd 20 inch monitor to replace the cave relic of a secondary monitor I used to use. I use a DVI-D cable for this. This has a 1600:900 resolution.

My primary Monitor is a 21 inch Emerson TV, that I run through HDMI. This has a 1366x768 native resolution. I have been using this since I had the computer built.

My computer is running windows 10.

If I go to the options and set it to display only through the TV (set as monitor 1) The resolution displays correctly. However when I set it to "extend these displays" the primary monitor displays incorrectly **even when native resolution is selected** in the settings.

I have done several searches, through the web and a couple through this website. However no one seems to have had this problem.

I have tried updating my drivers and rebooting, but not sure what else to do.

Edit: I have since changed a setting on the monitors, apparently the secondary monitor (AOC) was set to be primary. When I set the emerson tv back to being primary, the resolution displayed closer, but still isn't displaying right even on native resolution.

further attempts: 
I uninstalled and re installed my driver.

I looked for an overscan setting(wasn't one)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work, the TV wouldn't work in "normal" mode, I had to set it to "full screen" mode. Which won't display correctly when using only the primary monitor.

This monitor has been on two computers before this one. Even been paired up with an old 4:3 monitor on my current computer and had no issues with resolutions matching until now. But for some reason, it doesn't get along with the new monitor.